# Use Angular 8 and OpenLayers 3 in order to draw and delete temporary vector layers from a map

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer, angular

I have a project built with Angular 8 and OpenLayers 3. I want to be able to draw and also delete Polygons from a map. I tried to port this working [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html) into my project.

These are the interacting components.

- **sidebar.html**: contains the button to be clicked
- **sidebar.component**: calls the *next()* of the observable.
- **sidebar.service**: contains the implementation of an observable.
- **map.component**: in which we *subscribe()* to the observable and add a (temporary) vector layer.

With the following code I am able to draw polygons on the map, but i can't delete them.

In sidebar.html a button is set to call *addInteraction()*.

#### sidebar.html

```
  ...
  <mat-button-toggle value="Polygon" (change)="addInteraction()">Draw Polygon
    <mat-icon>crop_original</mat-icon></mat-button-toggle>
  <br><br/>
  ...
```

In the sidebar component we call *next()*

#### sidebar.component

```
  ...
  addInteraction() {
    this._sidebarService.nextDrawAOI('Polygon');
  }
  ...
```

In the sidebar service is were *next()* is implemented.

#### sidebar.service

```
  private drawAOI = new Subject<string>();

  ...
  getDrawAOI() {
    return this.drawAOI.asObservable();
  }
   ...
  nextDrawAOI(x) {
    this.drawAOI.next(x);
  }
```

In map component, subscribe() is called and . .

1. The Vector layer is created.
2. Draw, Snap and Modify interactions are added.
3. The map is added to the vector layer with *setMap(this.map)*. The layer won't get handled by the map but it will be temporarily added to it.

#### map.component

```
    ...
private polygonLayer: VectorLayer;
private polygonSource: VectorSource;
private modify: Modify;
private draw: Draw;
private snap: Snap;
    ...
ngAfterViewInit() {

..

// Layers
let source = new OlXYZ({
  ..
});

let layer = new OlTileLayer({
  ..
});

// View
let view = new OlView({
  ..
});

const mousePositionControl = new MousePosition({
   ...
});

// Map
this._map = new OlMap({
  controls: defaultControls().extend([
    scaleLineControl, mousePositionControl
  ]),
  interactions: OlXYZ.interactions,
  target: 'map',
  layers: [layer],
  view: view
});


this._sidebarService.getDrawAOI().pipe(map((x) => {
  this.polygonSource = new VectorSource({
    wrapX: false,
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  });
  this.polygonLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: this.polygonSource
  });

  this.modify = new Modify({source: this.polygonSource});
  this._map.addInteraction(this.modify);

  this._map.removeInteraction(this.draw);
  this._map.removeInteraction(this.snap);
  this.polygonLayer.setMap(null);

  this.draw = new Draw({
    source: this.polygonSource,
    type: x
  });
  this._map.addInteraction(this.draw);
  this.snap = new Snap({source: this.polygonSource});
  this._map.addInteraction(this.snap);

  this.polygonLayer.setMap(this._map);
  return x;
})).subscribe((x) => {
  console.log(x);
});


this._map.on('click', function(evt) {
```

> In the next line when an event is fired **this.polygonLayer** is *undefined* !

```
  var features = this.polygonLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
  features.forEach((feature) => {
    this.polygonLayer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
  });
});

}
```

The problem lies here.

> In the *map.component* i have placed the handler of an event.  When an event is fired, the vector layer (aka. *polygonLayer*) is undefined. It seems like the vector will not bind to *this*. Is this a binding problem? And if it is, why does this occur?